# Second order quantum coherence function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics

I have one question from the course of quantum optics.
In general the second order quantum coherence in time is defined as,

$$g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\left\langle E^{(-)}(t)E^{(-)}(t+\tau)E^{(+)}(t+\tau)E^{(+)}(t)\right\rangle}{\left\langle E^{(-)}(t)E^{(+)}(t)\right\rangle\left\langle E^{(-)}(t+\tau)E^{(+)}(t+\tau)\right\rangle}$$

For the single mode case, $E^{(+)}=i\epsilon \hat{a}e^{i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r-\omega t)}$,

$$g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\left\langle a ^\dagger a^\dagger(\tau) a(\tau) a\right\rangle}{\left\langle a^\dagger a\right\rangle\left\langle a^\dagger(\tau) a(\tau)\right\rangle}.$$

Now we consider the multimode case. It seems the definition should be

\begin{equation}
g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\left\langle \sum_{j,l}a_j ^\dagger a_l^\dagger(\tau) a_l(\tau) a_j\right\rangle}{\left\langle \sum_j a_j^\dagger a_j\right\rangle\left\langle \sum_j a_j^\dagger(\tau) a_j(\tau)\right\rangle}.
\end{equation}

where we suppose do the average on the multimode coherent state.

My question is that how to argue this from the general definition.

According to my understanding, if we do the average on the multimode coherent state, we have $E^{(+)}=\sum_j a_j$. If we start from the general definition, we will have the following,

$$g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\left\langle \sum_{j,l,m,n}a_j ^\dagger a_l^\dagger(\tau) a_m(\tau) a_n\right\rangle}{\left\langle \sum_j a_j^\dagger a_j\right\rangle\left\langle \sum_j a_j^\dagger(\tau) a_j(\tau)\right\rangle}.$$ 
It is very different from the third equation. Any ideas?